# Percircle Dynamic data not updating in vue js

Tags: vue.js, percircle

I am using percircle JS library with vue js.

Issue is when data comes from API, it is not reflecting in percircle. When I again run the API, it reflects there.

below is HTML code for percircle:

```
<div
:data-percent="receivedFilterData.visit_percentage_without_prescription"
class="small percircle red animate"
></div>
```

I used :data-percent to assign dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using `percircle`, Hemant. I guess porting percircle to vuejs would solve this issue. Therefore, I just opened a new issue, https://github.com/teobais/percircle/issues/85 .